# How to make a WCF publicly available through a website not hosted in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, http

I have written an AJAX-enabled WCF service that works well when debugging in Visual Studio. I consume the service in AngularJS using $http methods, such as the one shown below:

```
$http.get("http://localhost:63963/TestService.svc/MethodName")
```

The goal is to be able to consume the service in the same way, but through my own personal domain name. For example:

```
$http.get("http://mydomainname.com/TestService.svc/MethodName")
```

However, once I publish the website and start hosting it on my domain, none of the methods in the TestService.svc file are available. I believe this is because when I visit the address "http://mydomainname.com/TestService.svc", the file just downloads instead of executing.

My question is, how can I make the methods I created in my WCF service publicly available through my Domain name, without hosting my website in IIS or self-hosting within an application (I want to host my service over hostgator or something similar)? Please let me know if this is possible, and if so, how to achieve this.

Or, please suggest better ways to make the methods I wrote within my WCF service available over the internet (through HTTP requests).

Also, please note that I am very new to stack overflow, so please let me know what I can do to improve how I ask questions in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Downloaded file format and what does it contain?

Comment: Hosting WCF applications on IIS requires enabling additional .NET service features such as HTTP Activation feature in Windows, which might not be enabled on shared hosting environments by default (and I doubt they'd enable it even upon request). So, either make sure your hosting provider supports WCF hosting or use your own VPS or dedicated Windows server.

Comment: The downloaded file is the .svc file that I created pointing to my service. The content of the file in its entirety is "<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="ProjectName.Service1" %>".
Thanks Khalid. Ultimately, I just want to be able to write my own server-side methods that interact with a MySQL database. Can anyone recommend an API or something that allows you to do this?